# MongoDB: Is there any performance profit to make the DB name short?

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB.

I know there are performance benefits to make the column names of the documents short.

The question is for the DB name itself.

I don't know, but I guess the DB name is not in the document, so there is no performance profit for it.

Is this true?

I also want to know the short Collection name is beneficial or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain **why** shorter column names cause performance benefits? If you know that, can you provide any source, or even a benchmark?

Answer (score 1):

According to the official document from mongodb

```
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/index.html#namespaces
```

Database names can be max length of 64 characters.

There are no performance benefit from having a shorter database names or collections names.

Also there are no performance benefits in having shorter column names according to the official statement.

```
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-operations/
```

> Shortening field names reduces expressiveness and does not provide considerable benefit for larger documents and where document overhead is not of significant concern. Shorter field names do not reduce the size of indexes, because indexes have a predefined structure. In general, it is not necessary to use short field names.